# Wait for binding to AIDL is complete

Tags: android, asynchronous, intentservice, aidl

I'm calling an AIDL service from ***within*** an IntentService. Once binding to the AIDL service is done, the IntentService must pass a parameter to the AIDL service for execution.

Now since binding to the AIDL takes takes place asynchornously, I want the code in IntentService to wait it out, before passing the parameter to the AIDL service.

pseudoCode:

STEP 1: Bind to AIDL service

STEP 2: Pass parameter to AIDL service

In other words, STEP2 is reached even before STEP 1 completes, coz binding to AIDL is asynchronous. Then I get exceptions.

How do I wait for STEP 1 to complete, before STEP 2 executes ?

Answer (score 0):

You muse use `ServiceConnection.onServiceConnected()` to monitor connection to service.Once the binding is complete you will get callback in `onServiceConnected`

Below is documentation snippet present in Android [developers guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Basics)

> A client can bind to the service by calling bindService(). When it
>   does, it must provide an implementation of ServiceConnection, which
>   monitors the connection with the service. The bindService() method
>   returns immediately without a value, but when the Android system
>   creates the connection between the client and service, it calls
>   onServiceConnected() on the ServiceConnection, to deliver the IBinder
>   that the client can use to communicate with the service.

Comment: Hi Vipul. I set a boolean flag at the end of the onServiceConnected() method. Before calling STEP 2, I put an empty loop while (!flag) {}.

But the emulator hangs because of this.

Comment: Should I use **AsyncTask** ? I'm just worried about the complexity.